# Bicep Template for NIC breaks internet access when adding in Load Balancer Configuration

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-bicep, nic

I am trying to deploy the network interface card for a SQL Server VM, that will be placed as part of an AlwaysOn Availability Group and subsequently should be added to my Internal Load Balancer. This card will be created in advance of the VM itself.

My problem is that when the VM is created and the pre-created NIC is attached as part of the deployment, internet access for the VM doesn't seem to work.

[image]

I have tried created a NIC in the portal manually and attaching to the VM/Load Balancer manually and that seemed to work fine.

For reference, I have deployed a similar template to a different VM that doesn't require the NIC to be part of the backend address pool and that deploys no problem.

Do I need to add more properties than just a reference to the resourceId of the backend address pool in the load balancer to get this working?

```
    resource virtualNetwork 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2022-05-01' existing = {
  name: virtualNetworkName
  scope: resourceGroup(virtualNetworkResourceGroup)
}

resource virtualMachineNetworkInterfaceCardSubnet 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets@2022-05-01' existing = {
  name: virtualNetworkSubnetName
  parent: virtualNetwork
}

resource loadBalancer 'Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers@2022-05-01' existing = {
  name: loadBalancerName
  scope: resourceGroup(virtualNetworkResourceGroup)
}

resource loadBalancerBackendAddressPool 'Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/backendAddressPools@2022-05-01' existing = {
  name: loadBalancerBackendAddressPoolName
  parent: loadBalancer
}

resource virtualMachineNetworkInterfaceCard 'Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces@2022-05-01' = {
  name: '${virtualMachineName}-nic-01'
  location: resourceLocation
  tags: {
    associatedResource: virtualMachineName
    environmentCode: environmentCode
    loadBalancer: loadBalancerName
    resourceLocation: resourceLocation
  }
  properties: {
    dnsSettings: {
      dnsServers: [
      ]
    }
    enableAcceleratedNetworking: true
    enableIPForwarding: false
    ipConfigurations: [
      {
        name: '${virtualMachineName}-nic-01-configuration'
        properties: {
          loadBalancerBackendAddressPools: [
            {
              id: loadBalancerBackendAddressPool.id
            }
          ]
          
          primary: true
          privateIPAddress: networkInterfaceCardIPAddress
          privateIPAddressVersion: 'IPv4'
          privateIPAllocationMethod: 'Static'
          subnet: {
            id: virtualMachineNetworkInterfaceCardSubnet.id
          }
        
        }
      }
    ]
    nicType: 'Standard'
  }
}
```

Comment: do you have any nsg associated ?

Comment: Hi Thomas, there is an NSG associated with the subnet. The load balancer and VMs exist within the same subnet

Comment: Have you check NSG outbound rules ? Any rule to deny internet traffic ?

Comment: Yeah there was nothing blocking outbound traffic.
I have however found the fix, nothing to do with the NIC template at all.
From these two links [link]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/37890/internet-access-on-vms-in-internal-load-balancer-p.html and [link]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-outbound-connections 
I have discovered that by design VMs behind internal load balancers do not allow outbound internet traffic

Comment: You either need to give the VM a Public IP (Not an option) or associate a NAT gateway with the subnet the VMs are connected to. Alternatively, you can use a routing table to define a route to send all outbound internet traffic to an Azure Firewall

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the underlying error was nothing to do with the Bicep template for the NIC itself.

It is due to the fact, that by design, load balancers (internal and public) don't allow outbound internet access according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/37890/internet-access-on-vms-in-internal-load-balancer-p.html
and
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-outbound-connections

I have been able to get this working in my case by first assigning a NAT gateway to the subnet where the VMs/Load Balancer reside. I was also able to test forwarding the traffic via a routing table to an Azure firewall which also worked